# how to add custom marker in google earth api?

Tags: html, kml, google-earth, google-earth-plugin

Instead of the regular placemark that is a yellow pin. I want to instead use this icon.
http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/kml/pal3/icon39.png
I'm not sure if I have to import a KML file or if I can just use it by loading it up. If anyone can help me just post the icon somehwhere on google earth, I would appreciate it.
I looked through some google kml files, and guides, but couldn't get it to work.
Thanks

Comment: Post the KML that you have so far...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easy way:
If you are creating your KML file using the Google Earth client
right click the icon
choose 'properties'
click on the icon - top right
click on 'add custom icon'
paste in the URL to icon you want to use

otherwise you will need to edit the .kml file with some kind of text editor
find the  that is being used for the placemark in question
in the  change the  value to the URL of the icon you want

if you need help to find the correct style
look for placemark name and find its 
this normally has a '#' tag in front of it
do a search in your document for that style (removing the '#' tag)

sometimes that finds it straight away (if you see the  stuff there go for it)

otherwise you will need to find both the styles (2 of them) listed under it (use same approach as above)
then proceed to change the  for the  in BOTH places

Comment: I think I'm getting close, I appreciate the help.

Comment: You have got it working, however in your danger.kml file, you left in a <camera> view associated to the <document>. Remove the <camera> view but leave the placemarks <lookat> and the page will load fine and result in a top-down view looking at your placemark with the icon you wish to use